# monitor the number of confirmations of multiple transactions

Tags: confirmations

I know I can get a number of confirmations one by one, but is there a easy way to monitor the number of confirmations of multiple transactions?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be storing the transaction IDs to check in an array and iterate over them, checking their number of verifications and removing the ID from the array when the required amount of confirmations is reached.

Comment: That's the only way I came up with. Thanks Nikita!